# Shell, For loop into directories and sub directory not working as intended

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, recursion

When trying to do a simple script that tars the files and moves them to another directory i'am having problems implementing the recursive loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
for directorio in $1; do #my thought process: start for loop goes into dir
    for file in $directorio; do #enter for loop for files
        fwe="${file%.*}" #file_without_extension    
        tar -czPf "$fwe.tar.bz2" "$(pwd)" && mv "$fwe.tar.bz2" /home/cunha/teste
    done
done
```

the script seems to be doing nothing ...
when the script is called like:  ./script.sh /home/blablabla

**How could i get this fixed?**

Comment: fixed it! still not working as i want it tho :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can better follow below option. How will it work? First it will list all the directories in `short_list.txt`. In while loop it will read each directory name and zip it in location `/home/cunha/teste`

```
find $1 -type d -name "*" > short_list.txt
cdr=$(pwd)

while read line
do
   cd $line
   base=$(basename $PWD)
   cd ..
   tar -cf /home/cunha/teste/$base.tar.gz  $base
done < short_list.txt
cd $cdr
rm -rf short_list.txt
```

Comment: i'm having an error when trying your method.
tar: /home/cunha/teste//home/cunha/sistemas_operativos/recursividade/.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: /home/cunha/teste//home/cunha/sistemas_operativos/recursividade/mini_recursividade.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: @storms, I have modified my answer now try.